# ShareOpenGraphContent for MessageDialog

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, messagedialog

Can I use ShareOpenGraphContent for MessageDialog?

When I create a ShareOpenGraphContent complete with its ShareOpenGraphAction and ShareOpenGraphObject and post it using ShareDialog.show() it works. Friends can see the post.

But when I create the same content and use MessageDialog.show() to send as a message to friends it says Attachment Unavailable.

this is my code in creating the content:

```
// Builds the object    
    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("fb:app_id", my_app_ID)
            .putString("og:url", link_to_site)
            .putString("og:type", objectType)
            .putString("og:title", contentTitle)
            .putString("og:description", contentDescription)
            .putString("og:image", imageLink)
            .build();

// Builds the action
        ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
                .setActionType(actionName)
                .putObject(objectName, object)
                .build();

// Create the openGraphContent
        ShareOpenGraphContent openGraphContent = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
                .setPreviewPropertyName(objectName)
                .setAction(action)
                .build();

        return openGraphContent;
```

i use that code for both ShareDialog.show() and MessageDialog.show()